# nodejs and socket.io with lua server developement

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, lua, socket.io

Need some advice on building server with lua written code and nodejs & socket.io. I heard that  lua is faster so I would like to write server in lua. and websockets with socket.io. In my basic idea luvit, nodelua,etc.. are lua modules for nodejs.

Now I need to know which module is best for building server with lua ,nodejs and socket.io?

remember I would use mongodb for data storage.

suggest me a suitable module!

thanks in advance.

Comment: why not go with `node.js` all the way ?

Comment: lua is faster and easy to code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/creationix/moonslice-luv

Moonslice is a collection of interfaces and lua libraries.

It's a mix of the code and technology from the luvit project mixed with some new experimental APIs that are designed to make it more lua friendly and easier to code